# How to replace NaN values with another column's mean based on value in another column? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have got a dataframe of game releases and ratings

```
name,platform,year_of_release,genre,na_sales,eu_sales,jp_sales,other_sales,critic_score,user_score,rating
Wii Sports,Wii,2006.0,Sports,41.36,28.96,3.77,8.45,76.0,8.0,E
Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985.0,Platform,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,,,
Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008.0,Racing,15.68,12.76,3.79,3.29,82.0,8.3,E
Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009.0,Sports,15.61,10.93,3.28,2.95,80.0,8.0,E
Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996.0,Role-Playing,11.27,8.89,10.22,1.0,,,
```

I want to fill NaN values in user_score column with the mean of the same genre. If a game has sports genre and in that row user_score is NaN i want replace the null value with sport's average user rating.

Comment: None of the NaNs in your sample data have any other values to average

Comment: in super mario game user_score is Null so I want replace that value with platform's average

Comment: Yes, and it's the onlly Platform genre in your data set, so there is nothing to average

Comment: So you want platform, not genre

Comment: I think @Neekunj meant `Platform` genre, not `platform` the column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data has had the user_score of the second sports game removed so that we can demonstrate the code.

```
name,platform,year_of_release,genre,na_sales,eu_sales,jp_sales,other_sales,critic_score,user_score,rating
Wii Sports,Wii,2006.0,Sports,41.36,28.96,3.77,8.45,76.0,8.0,E
Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985.0,Platform,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,,,
Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008.0,Racing,15.68,12.76,3.79,3.29,82.0,8.3,E
Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009.0,Sports,15.61,10.93,3.28,2.95,80.0,,E
Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996.0,Role-Playing,11.27,8.89,10.22,1.0,,,
```

Looking at the user score of the Wii Sports Resort

```
df.iloc[3]['user_score']

nan
```

Replacing NaN with the mean of the user_score by genre

```
df['user_score'] = df.groupby('genre')['user_score'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Checking the output of the same game after the update

```
df.iloc[3]['user_score']

8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a dictionary `genre_avg` of genre average ratings and then substitute NAs in `user_score` according to this dictionary

```
genre_avg = data.groupby(['genre']).agg({'user_score': 'mean'})['user_score'].to_dict()
data['user_score'] = data['user_score'].fillna(data['genre'].map(genre_avg))
```

---

*In your small sample data nothing changes, because none of the `NaNs` have any other values to average. However, if for instance you change the `genre` of `Wii Sports` from `Sports` to `Platform`, you will see that `Super Mario Bros.` will have its `user_score` filled with the average of the `Platform` genre games.*